# Reading doubles from .txt file into a List

Tags: java, list, double, text-files

I'm trying to read doubles from a .txt file and put them all into a list.

Here's my code so far ->

(I have one method to ask for the file and get the data stream, and one to put the doubles into a list.)

```
    public InputFile () throws MyException {
    fileIn = null;
    dataIn = null;
    do {
        filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the file called? ");
        try {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream((filename + ".txt"));
            dataIn = new DataInputStream(fileIn);

            return;
        }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no "+filename + ".txt");
        }
   }
   while (   Question.answerIsYesTo("Do you want to retype the file name")   );
   throw new MyException("No input file was chosen");
}
```

That part works fine.

```
        public ProcessMain() {
        boolean EOF = false;

    List <Double> allNumbers = new ArrayList <Double> () ;

            try {

                InputFile inputFile = new InputFile();

                        while(EOF == false) {
                        try {
                          allNumbers.add(inputFile.dataIn.readDouble());
                            }
                        catch(EOFException e){ EOF = true; }
                        }

         // List manipulation here. I have no problems with this part.

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

     System.out.println(allNumbers);
```

I get the following -

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Any ideas?

Comment: What's an `InputFile2`? Did you mean `InputFile inputFile2 = new InputFile()`? What line of code throws the exception?

Comment: yeah, I put the 2 in by mistake.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `new Double()` constructor. You can pass a `double` directly to `allNumbers.add()` and it will be [autoboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to a `Double`. If you want to box the `double` explicitly, use [`Double#valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `new Double()` - in which case you don't need to parse the string yourself, because `Double#valueOf()` can take a string.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not getting an exception anymore, but the only output is '[]'. 

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read my suggestion about not using DataInputStream?

Answer (score 2):

`DataInputStream` is really for reading binary data, e.g. from a socket. I think what you want is just simple `FileReader` and then parse using `Double.parseDouble(String)` or `Double.valueOf(String)` - depending on whether you want to get primitive or Object doubles.

If your input file contains each number on a new line, you can use `BufferedReader.readLine`. Otherwise you will need some simple parsing, e.g. to find space or comma-separated values.

So for example, to read a file containing each number on a new line you could do something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class DoubleReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Double d = Double.valueOf(line);
        System.err.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

But if your file separates the numbers differently (e.g. space or comma) you will need to do a bit of extra/different work while reading the file to extract (parse) your values.

[Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is about tokenizing your data so you can extract the bits you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like it would be the way to go. 

So instead of a DataInpuStream, I'd just need a FileReader?

Could you elaborate a little on the .parseDouble() and parsing in general?

Thanks a lot! I think I was digging myself into a hole with the DataInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the "EOF = false" line.. that assigns "false" to "EOF" and will always be true.  Try changing it to "EOF == false".

Comment: Or ( ! EOF ). Yes (EOF=false) will assign false to EOF and evaluate to false, that terminates the loop before it reads anything giving you an empty array and hence the exception

Comment: It catches and discard EOFException to se the EOF and break the loop. :P

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream` is only for reading things written with the corresponding output stream. For a text file, create an `InputStreamReader` around your `FileInputStream` (remembering to specify the encoding), and then a `BufferedReader` so that you can read by lines. Then use the Double class to parse the strings.